# Why choose "bo" over "bam" in Ne'ilah?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, words, yom-kippur

In the Shabbat *davening* there is the phrase "*v'yanuchu ____ yisra'el*..." The middle word, according to the Artscroll text, is "*bah*" in *ma'ariv, "bo"* in *shacharit* and *musaf* and "*bam*" in *mincha*. This is explained with a reference to the Magen Avraham (O"C 268:3) that the word refers to 3 separate items: the sabbath of creation (the feminine form), the sabbath at *Matan Torah* (masculine) and the sabbath of the future (plural). I don't know if this system is in use in other *siddurim* so I am basing my question on this text.

On A Yom Kippur that coincides with Shabbat, this phrase is inserted in the *amidah*. The uses follow that pattern until *Ne'ilah.* On pages 716 and 754, the text is given as "*bo*."

Does this attest to something about the nature of *Ne'ilah*? Is it chosen for any particular reason?

Comment: I don’t know about your Artscroll text, but mine definitely has Bam.

Comment: @doni artscroll has changed with editions